# Visual Studio 2015 System.Net.HttpWebRequest System.IO.IOException while Debug Run but Not via Compiled EXE

Tags: windows, debugging, exception, visual-studio-2015, symantec

The 2019 new year brought this debug exception in my Visual Studio 2015 code below. The only thing that works is running the compiled EXE or using a Visual Studio 2010 with the same internet third party API calls. We've got an updated Symantec Endpoint Protection installed that we adjusted every which way but Sunday to no avail. My associate uninstalled Symantec and we've both rebooted multiple times without relief.

```
2019-01-03 08:56:47.3326|ERROR|...:
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. --->
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean reserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
```

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Comment: Attaching to the running EXE does provide a work around for now.

Comment: Opening the EXE file from inside VS and then "Start Debuging" does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The same day the problem started was the same day our third party provider of web APIs stopped supporting TLS 1.0. As I understand TLS, Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 will default to TLS 1.0. The quick fix was to use this VB.NET code in front of the first API call:
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Long term we'll eliminate the WebRequest calls per Microsoft:
"Important

We don't recommend that you use WebRequest or its derived classes for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class."